# sudo apt update failed in ubuntu 20.04. Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, software-center, update-manager

Trying to do `sudo apt-get update` for ubuntu 20.04 but it shows an error like this:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have attached [my screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ZN8.png). Can anyone please help with it?

My sources.list screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9741e.png)

/etc/apt =>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWnRS.png)

Output of dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iuME.png)

Comment: What is your actual machine architecture (`uname -m`)? You seem to have a mix of "amd64" and "arm64" in your sources.list

Comment: @steeldriver it says x86_64

Comment: So why do you have arm64 in your sources? In particular, why do you have things like `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages` (apparently trying to pull amd64 packages from the ports repo) and `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages` (apparently trying to pull arm64 packages from the regular repo)?

Comment: Yeah, actually i messed all of my sources.list file by copying everyone of them without having any prior knowledge. What shall i do to solve this?  @steeldriver

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include the content of the edited file(s) (`/etc/apt/sources.list` and any in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` that you may have modified) maybe someone will be able to offer some suggestions. As a last resort, see [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: @steeldriver I have attached my contents of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I'd suggest commenting out (`#`) all the `ubuntu-ports` entries (i.e. the first 8 entries) and then seeing if `sudo apt update` runs without errors

Comment: E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
@steeldriver.  Tried. It gave error like this

Comment: So did you check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for other `.list` files? I don't see anything in the file you posted that would result in those errors. Look for lines possibly containing `[arch=arm64]`.

Comment: @steeldriver there is sources.list.d file in /etc/apt and no lines containing [arch=arm64]. I have attached my /etc/apt/ folder

Comment: See this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/877051/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it did not worked as well

Comment: @immingmar please show us the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Comment: @steeldriver It's i386 and arm64. I have attached the screenshot as well.

Comment: @immingmar please no more screenshots of text! You can try to remove the incompatible foreign architecture with `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture arm64`

Comment: @steeldriver Finally, it worked!! Thanks!

Comment: @steeldriver Please consider posting an answer.